# ElasticSearch / Kibana issue - "Drag zoom" gives inconsistent timestamps? clarification on panel intervals?

Tags: timestamp, elasticsearch, kibana

New to ElasticSearch and Kibana. I am working with data that I need to show daily (not hourly, etc.) I am timestamping as the last second of the day in question. I am wanting to use a histogram.

For whatever reason, when I have the Panel interval set to 1d or 1hr, the "drag to zoom" function seems wildly inconsistent. When I try and zoom to see the most current data (e.g. 12/19), the histo cuts off the day before and doesn't reflect the most current data (e.g shows 12/18 as most current). It generally seems to cut off at 4AM. Also, the timepicker usually stops the day before I need, sometimes with a 4AM timestamp, sometimes 5AM.

Here are screenshots to demonstrate the discrepancies between all these time ranges:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/781

I have changed my time stamp to account for UTC, etc with no luck and I am not sure what to do.

My questions:

1. Is there a timestamp config in the mapping I need to define?
2. Since exact time of day is not important (but showing the data for the most recent date is), how should I format my timestamp?
3. For monitoring daily data, what should my histogram time interval be? I'd prefer to use 1d as long as I can see the last day posted.

If I can understand how Kibana handles timestamps, as well as understand the panel interval settings, I am hopeful I can solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else who finds this post, the OP got their answer in the ES link they provided.